# Output once if both xml tags occur at the same time

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

If both xml tags exist I only want the output of the transform to occur once. Is that possible?

**xsl**

```
<xsl:template match="latitude | longitude">
   <generate_once>for both tags below</generate_once>
</xsl:template>
```

**xml**

```
<doc>
<latitude /><longitude />
</doc>
```

Comment: I want to apologize ahead of time if this seems like an invalid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this template do the trick...?

```
<xsl:template match="latitude | longitude[not(../latitude)]">
   <generate_once>for both tags below</generate_once>
</xsl:template>
```

This works by matching `latitude` if it exists (regardless of whether there is a `longitude` or not). It will only match `longitude` if there is no `latitude` though. So, in the case of both being present, only the `latitude` is matched.

Comment: hmm, my initial test says "it works!" Can you share some insight to a xslt newbie as to how that works? Do you see any possible caveats?

Comment: I've added a bit more explanation to my answer. The answer does assume both `latitude` and `longitude` have the same parent though.